# Using regular expression, list all the letters that follows a vowel according to their occurrence frequency

Tags: python, regex

How can I find consonants letters that came after the vowels in words of string and count the frequency

```
str = 'car regular double bad '
result19 = re.findall(r'\b\w*[aeiou][^ aeiou]\w*\b' , str)
print(result19) #doesn't work
```

**Expected output**

```
letter r count  = 2
letter b count = 1
letter d count = 1
```

Comment: Why isn't there `l` in your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether this is what you want or not, but it might help as an answer and not a comment.

I think you are on the right track, but you need a few modifications and other lines to achieve the excepted:

```py
import re
myStr = 'car regular double bad '
result19 = re.findall(r'[aeiou][^aeiou\s]+' , myStr)
myDict = {}
for value in result19:
  if not value[1] in myDict:
    myDict[value[1]] = 0
  myDict[value[1]] += 1
myDict
```

This will result in a dictionary containing the values and the number the have appeared:

```
{'b': 1, 'd': 1, 'g': 1, 'l': 1, 'r': 2}
```

For having a better output you can use a for loop to print each key and its value:

```py
for chr, value in myDict.items():
  print(chr, "->", value)
```

##### Output

```
r -> 2
g -> 1
l -> 1
b -> 1
d -> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern `\b\w*[aeiou][^ aeiou]\w*\b` matches zero or more repetitions of a word character using `\w*` and only matches a single occurrence of `[aeiou][^ aeiou]` in the "word"

If you want to match all consonant letters based on the alphabet a-z after a vowel, you can match a single occurrence of `[aeiou]` and  use a capture group matching a single consonant.

Then make use of re.findall to return a list of the group values.

```
import re

txt = 'car regular double bad '
lst = re.findall(r'[aeiou]([b-df-hj-np-tv-z])', txt)
dct = {c: lst.count(c) for c in lst}

print(dct)
```

Output

```
{'r': 2, 'g': 1, 'l': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1}
```

If you want to match a non whitespace char other than a vowel after matching a vowel, you can use this pattern `[aeiou]([^\saeiou])`

**Note** that the `l` is also in the output as it comes after the `u` in  `ul`